# Display instructions for infected on every respawn

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I understand that you can enable the instruction mode in the multiplayer menu (not sure how it's called in English, in German it's "Spielanleitung"), which shows the attacks of the infected after the first respawn. For example left click to jump on the back of another player.

But is there a possibility to let L4D display these instructions *on every respawn*? (Probably the game thinks, I'm better than I actually am :))

Comment: When this option is enabled, it *should* display on every spawn. The crappy part is when it randomly enables itself for a game or two, seemingly a bug. Are you not seeing it on every new spawn? Or do you mean *re*-spawn where you run backwards on the map while alive to respawn invisibly near the survivors?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in options->video for tooltips or hints or something of the like, I remember that I had disabled that one day when it kept annoying me.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in the video options. The only thing is the "instruction mode" that I have mentioned, this can be enabled in the "Multiplayer" settings.